# Creating a parallax image in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create an animated "parallax" image in React-Native. I have a static background image and two individual images as an overlay. The goal is to create something similar to the image found on this website http://www.digitalhands.net/ or https://www.galaxia.co/. Where do I even start with this? Initially I'd be happy with it moving just on itself from left to right and etc. Afterwards I want to make it so that it would use the gyroscope to get the x and y values for animating the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A parallax effect consists of images moving in different speeds and in the same direction, such that the 'closer' an object is, the faster it moves, which creates the illusion of three dimensions.

To achieve this effect in react-native, you can use the [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated.html) library to interpolate the position of one image as a fraction of the position of another.

For the sake of an example, let's assume you want the parallax effect in the vertical direction, and that all images are positioned at 0 vertically.

First, you would need an animated value in your component's state:

```
this.state = {
    ...
    imagePos: new Animated.Value(0)
}
```

Then, for each `Image` style you can add a transform on its y axis:

```
<Animated.Image src={...} style={[firstImageStyle, {
        transform: [{translateY: this.state.imagePos.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 100]
        })}]
    }]}

<Animated.Image src={...} style={[secondImageStyle, {
        transform: [{translateY: this.state.imagePos.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [0, 50]
        })}]
    }]}
```

*Note the use of `Animated.Image` instead of `Image` to make the image animatable.*

This would cause the first image to move horizontally between 0-100 dp when `imagePos` has values between 0 and 1, and the second image to move between 0-50 dp.

To change the value of the animated value you can use any of the functions in the `Animated` library (timing, spring, decay, etc.) or you can attach it to some native event.

The animated library documentation has much more detail.

As for the use of the gyroscope, I haven't gone into the details, but you can probably use [react-native-sensors](https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors) or [react-native-motion-manager](https://github.com/pwmckenna/react-native-motion-manager) to get the values you need, and attach them to the animation.

Comment: Tried your solution but `imagePos: Animated.Value(0)` throws an error. `Cannot call a class as a function`

Comment: This worked perfectly coupled with the Animated.timing attribute and the react-native-sensors library. Just what I needed.

Comment: Worked for me but after I added this `var imagePos = new Animated.Value(0);` instead of setting state like this `imagePos: new Animated.Value(0)` as it threw error 'undefined state imagepos'

Comment: Expo has an easy method to get Gyroscope information - https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/devicemotion/

Answer (score 0):

By using a package like https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors I managed to get the x, y, z values of the phones position and animate an image with it.

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Normal RxJS functions
    accelerationObservable
        .subscribe(({x, y, z}) => this.setState({
          x: x,
          y: y,
          z: z,
        }));
  }

  render() { return (
      <Image style={{left: this.state.x + this.state.y, top: this.state.z}}
                   source={require('image.png')}/>
    )
  }
```