# How to keep image view in same place, but image itself in different position. Reac Native

Tags: css, image, react-native

```
  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.activeIndi}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    } else {
      let date = moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY"); // August 29th 2018, 11:12:55 pm // Wed, Aug 29, 2018 11:05 PM
      let launches = this.state.dataSource.map((item, key) => {
        return (
          <View key={key}>
            <View style={styles.homeContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.homeText}>Home</Text>
              <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.dateText}>{date}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.launchBackground}>
              <Text style={styles.launchText}>
                Launching Soon: {item.missions[0].name}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <Image
              style={{
                width: "100%",
                height: 300
              }}
              source={{
                uri: item.rocket.imageURL
              }}
            />
          </View>
        );
      });
      return <View>{launches}</View>;
    }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  activeIndi: {
    marginTop: "80%"
  },
  dateContainer: {
    marginTop: "11.5%"
  },
  dateText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#383838"
  },
  homeContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "16%",
    backgroundColor: "white",
    alignItems: "center",
    shadowColor: "grey",
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowRadius: 3,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: -1 }
  },
  homeText: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "#383838",
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: "left",
    position: "absolute",
    bottom: 20
  },
  launchText: {
    marginTop: "1%",
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "left",
    left: "3%",
    color: "#383838",
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  launchBackground: {
    height: 35,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 1,
    borderColor: "rgba(249, 249, 249,.6)"
  }
});
```

[image: Image of problem]

The problem i have is that i want to keep the image frame in the same place but the image itself in a different position so you get to see the top of the rocket. I tried playing around with the transform tool but that didn't work. I also tried downloading a cropping package to but that ruined my whole project.

Comment: Have you tried nesting your `Image` component inside a `View` giving it the `height` and `width` you want and  playing with aligns to show the exact part of image you want?

Comment: i have not, ill give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want but by the looks of it, it feels like you want a parallax image. There are alot of libraries out there, a quick search got me to one of these:

> https://github.com/danny8903/react-native-parallax-background
>
> https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-parallax-scroll-view

I personally haven't used them, but they seem to be up to date with easy getting started instructions. Give them a go.

or you can have a look at this answer which does it manually for you

> [Creating a parallax image in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864141/creating-a-parallax-image-in-react-native)